# Problem when I want to display textures in one face of a 3d cube in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Today, I'm trying to display two textures in one of the faces of a 3d cube. I achieved my goal.
The problem is on the other faces, their display weird textures also.

I check the coordinates of the texture and only the main face is represented.

```
private float textureCord[] = {
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        // Front face
        1.2f, 1.2f,
        1.2f, -0.2f,
        -0.2f, -0.2f,
        -0.2f, 1.2f
};
```

Secondly, I add these lines in order to prevent repetitions.

```
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

It helps, but still not working properly.

[image: Result]

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Cubo class:

```
public class Cubo {

private Context context;
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec4 aColor;" +
                "varying vec4 vColor;" +
                "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate0;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate0;" +
                "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate1;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate1;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  vColor=aColor;" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "  v_TexCoordinate0 = a_TexCoordinate0;" +
                "  v_TexCoordinate1 = a_TexCoordinate1;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture0;" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;" +
                "uniform vec4 aColor;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate0;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate1;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   vec4 base = texture2D(u_Texture0, v_TexCoordinate0);" +
                "   vec4 overlay = texture2D(u_Texture1, v_TexCoordinate1);" +
                "   mediump float ra = (overlay.a) * overlay.r + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.r;" +
                "   mediump float ga = (overlay.a) * overlay.g + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.g;" +
                "   mediump float ba = (overlay.a) * overlay.b + (1.0 - overlay.a) * base.b;" +
                "   vec3 textureColor = vec3(ra, ga, ba);" +
                "   float textureAlpha = max(base.a, overlay.a);" +
                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(aColor.rgb, textureColor, textureAlpha), 1.0);" +
                "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;


static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float cubeCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // bottom right
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // top right
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // top left back
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   // bottom left back
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   // bottom right back
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f  // top right back
};

private final short drawOrder[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
        3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 7,
        0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 4,
        1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
        4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0,
        7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 4};

private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;


float color[] = {0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f};

private float textureCord[] = {
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        // Front face
        1.2f, 1.2f,
        1.2f, -0.2f,
        -0.2f, -0.2f,
        -0.2f, 1.2f
};

private int[] textures = new int[2];

private int[] bitmapsId = {
        R.drawable.horizontal,
        R.drawable.casilla27
};


public Cubo(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            cubeCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(cubeCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCord.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCord);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    //---------------textura-------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < textures.length; i++) {
        int mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_Texture" + i);
        int mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_TexCoordinate" + i);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, mTextureBuffer);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(i == 0 ? GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 : GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, i);
    }
    //------------------------------------------
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}

public void loadTexture() {
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, textures, 0);
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < textures.length; i++) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), bitmapsId[i], options);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

}

Renderer:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


private Cubo cubo;
private Context context;
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix_x = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix_y = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

private float mXAngle;
private float mYAngle;

public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    cubo = new Cubo(context);
    cubo.loadTexture();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i1) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, i, i1);
    float ratio = (float) i / i1;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix_x, 0, mYAngle, 1.0f, 0, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix_y, 0, mXAngle, 0, 1.0f,  0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix_y, 0, mRotationMatrix_x, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
    cubo.draw(scratch);
}


public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

public float getmXAngle() {
    return mXAngle;
}

public void setmXAngle(float mXAngle) {
    this.mXAngle = mXAngle;
}

public float getmYAngle() {
    return mYAngle;
}

public void setmYAngle(float mYAngle) {
    this.mYAngle = mYAngle;
}
```

Comment: When you make a plain cube with no textures, you can get away with creating only 8 vertices, because each vertex has the exact same data (position) for all three adjacent faces. This cannot be done if you are mapping textures onto the faces (unless the texture is supposed to wrap directly across the vertex, which is typically not what you'd want to do with a cube). So you need to define 24 vertices instead of 8. Some vertices will have identical position data, but their texture coordinates will be different. You would also need 24 vertices if you add normals data so it can have lighting.

Comment: Hi Tenfour04, thank you! I change my cubeCoords of 8 vertices to one of 24. Now the cube looks worse. I think I don't understand you, sorry. I change my cubeCoords  to the vertices of this example that I found : [link](https://github.com/digi-embedded/android-sample-openglrotatingcube/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/digi/android/sample/rotatingcube/opengl/cube/PhotoCube.java)

Comment: After I spend some time investigating, I realize that it's necessary to change de
drawOrder too. Now looks good. Thank you so much, Tenfour04!